# Git Delete status show on changes

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I don't when the files are added to my project but there is no use in this file. Whenever I check the changes they show many files how to remove them permanently

see the screenshot of my project
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNakW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **.gitignore** file to your solution.

Use the below steps to add **.gitignore** and **.gitattributes** file:

Open Visual Studio and the solution needing an ignore file. From the top menu select **Git > Settings.**

[image]

The above will open Visual Studio’s Options with Source Control > Git Global Settings selected. From the list on the left select Git Repository Settings and then click the Add button for Ignore file.

[image]

The above will add a .gitignore file with all the proper files ignored for a typical Visual Studio setup. Switch to the Git Changes window and enter a commit message and then click the Commit Staged button to commit the change to your current working branch.

[image]

**Stop tracking files that should be ignored**

To stop tracking the files in the ignore file open a command prompt and navigate to the directory that contains your solution file (.sln) and run the following commands.

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git add .
git commit -am "Remove ignored files"
```